# HTML to PDF using XSL FO is having pagination issue - displays only the first page

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo, apache-fop, html-to-pdf

I'm using a Java class(http://pastebin.com/KhSGPmCV) that takes in an HTML document and tries to convert it to a PDF document by the following steps:

1. Uses Tidy to parse it into an XML document.
2. Uses an XSLT style sheet(http://pastebin.com/s45gRTKy) to covert
   the xml into an FO document
3. Uses Apache FoP to convert from FO to PDF document.

The problem that I am facing is only the first page of my HTML document is getting converted to PDF. The warning message that i see is -

`Mar 2, 2013 2:53:06 PM org.apache.fop.events.LoggingEventListener processEvent
 WARNING: Content overflows the viewport of an fo:block-container in block-progression direction by 350 millipoints. Content will be clipped. (See position 51:261)`

I'm pretty certain that the problem is in the XSL FO style sheet that I'm using. But, even after adding/modifying a lot of variables in this style sheet, I'm unable to get the 2nd page as visible. Could anyone please help me out?

Link to the HTML that I'm trying to convert to PDF - [pastebin.com/iBLw8Pbv](http://pastebin.com/iBLw8Pbv)

Answer (score 1):

You're using Apache FOP to build a PDF. Read this very important note in the xsl:

> Since this stylesheet is originally developed by Antenna House to be
>   used with XSL Formatter, **it may not be compatible with another XSL-FO
>   processors**.

You may be forced to use Antenna is you expect a nice output. If you can get a binary, the script below might help (Ubuntu). If you use the xsl anyway: `<nobr>` is not in that xsl... in your HTML you must replace it with `<pre>`. Another problem is that tidy doesn't seem to fix end quotes and will generate a LOT of warnings about bad @ids (some @ids will contain the @class).

I have no idea on how to fix this. I don't have fop on my classpath so I needed this:

```
javac -cp .:/usr/share/java/fop.jar:/usr/share/java/jtidy.jar Html2PDF.java 
java -cp .:/usr/share/java/fop.jar:/usr/share/java/jtidy.jar Html2PDF samplehtml.txt xhtml2fo.xsl
```

And I wrote this simple script that will help a lot as you debug:

```
# remove broken IDs
sed "s/id=\"[^\"]* //g" samplehtml.txt > samplehtml.txt.fixedID

# use tidy
tidy -utf8 -w 255 -indent -quiet -asxhtml < samplehtml.txt.fixedID > samplehtml.txt.tidy

# change 
#   -  &nbsp; to &$160;
#   -  remove xmlns declaration
#   -  <nobr to <pre ;; </nobr to </pre
sed -e "s/nbsp/#160/g;s/<html [^>]*/<html/;s/<nobr/<pre/g;s/<\/nobr/<\/pre/g" samplehtml.txt.tidy > samplehtml.txt.tidy2
xalan -xsl xhtml2fo.xsl -in samplehtml.txt.tidy2 -out res.fo
fop res.fo res.pdf
```

Edit: I found a neat project that does what you need, and the output looks great. https://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/

Comment: You're welcome! I hope you get it figured out. Also I found this today and actually worked with your complex html file: https://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/